# Validating Account_No with Customer tabe Account_No

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to match the customers entered `Account_No` which is in `customers` table  `[Cus_ID] ,[Name] ,[Email] ,[Account_No]  FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer]`. Now i have a page where i have to write again that Account_No, Now if i enter some invalid `Account_No` there again then it must give me a message that `You entered invalid Account_No`. For that, i have tried the following code but every time it prompts me to `You entered invalid Account_No`. Please have a look on it. Thank you.
First i tried this code...

```
int d;
        if (Session["UserCheck"] != null)
        {
            //Retrieving CustomerID from Session
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);
            //  lblCusID.Text = "Cus_ID : " + d;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        // Getting Account_No from Customers and matching with enterd Account_No in txtAcntNo.Text
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer] where Account_No = '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "' ", con);
        //SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Account_No FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer] where Cus_ID = '" + d + "' ", con);
        con.Open();
        var acc = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();

        if (acc == txtAcntNo.Text)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Transfer_Pay]([User_ID] ,[Bank_Name], [Account_No] ,[Date]) VALUES ('" + d + "' ,'" + txtBnkame.Text + "', '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "', GETDATE())";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("/shipments.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('You entere invalid Account_No!')</script>");
        }
```

and after failure of this, i tried this...

```
int d;
        if (Session["UserCheck"] != null)
        {
            //    //Retrieving UserName from Session
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);
            //  lblCusID.Text = "Cus_ID : " + d;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        if (txtBnkame.Text == "" || txtAcntNo.Text == "")
        {
            Response.Redirect("transfer_pay.aspx");
        }

        else
        {
            string a = "0";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer] where Account_No = '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "' ", con);
            SqlDataReader r;
            con.Open();
            r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (r.Read())
            {
                r.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                r.Close();
                con.Close();
                //lblError.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password !";
                Response.Write("<script>alert('You entere invalid Account_No!')</script>");
            }
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Transfer_Pay]([User_ID] ,[Bank_Name], [Account_No] ,[Date]) VALUES ('" + d + "' ,'" + txtBnkame.Text + "', '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "', GETDATE())";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("/shipments.aspx");
        }
```

Here is image of the page, from where i'm entering the `Account_No`
[image: page image]

Comment: Does your connection point to correct DB which contains records for provided account number? Also Execute scalar will give you first row and column value instead of your desired column. so you need to change your select query as follows :
`select * FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer] where Account_No = '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "'`

Comment: That's the same query as i have written

Comment: Copied incorrectly. here is the correct query : `select Account_No FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer] where Account_No = '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "'`

Comment: no sake ... Same problem